# Invalid charectes showing in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

When i am loading data to my hive tables i am getting below characters prefixed to the first cell (First column, first raw)

∩╗┐1

1 is the value in my source .csv file

Can some one help

Comment: column data type was 'string' when i was getting above issue, now i changed it to 'int' and loaded data from same file(s). But it created different issue, instead of inavild character, it showing 'NULL' now.

Comment: Please share the file format and create table statement.

Comment: @Arani : i pasted both line below as 2 comments

Comment: CREATE TABLE phone2 (BusinessEntityID string, PhoneNumber string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

Comment: LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/ambady/Phone.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE phone2;

Comment: If you have defined two columns for your table, why does your file contain only one value? Also, can you share how the data file looks?